# Query results to list in SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I'm sure this is discussed somewhere, but after searching for a while I can't find it.

I'm building a stored procedure for SQL 2000 and I need to build a list of numbers that I can use in an IN function.

The query looks like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM dbo.table WHERE building = @currentBuilding
```

This will return typically between 1-5 results, I'm looking for a way to put that into an nvarchar or something.

I would like to dream there is an easy way to do this since it's in 1 column but I have a feeling I'm going to end up iterating over the results.

As a side, is nvarchar the right variable to use? is there a better way I could store these that would make IN work faster?

Thanks!

Comment: I take it that there is some reason that you can't just put the query directly into the `IN` clause?

Comment: @Martin Smith: I could just put it into the IN clause, but I have to use it many times, so I figured it would be easier on the server if I stored it as a variable.

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends how expensive it is to calculate. By removing the query from it's original context you might be robbing the query optimiser of some optimisation chances depending on how you are using it. I presume that you are now having to use either dynamic SQL or a split function to use this? If so a single column table variable with `PRIMARY KEY` on column `type` might be better unless you need to pass the list around between different procedures.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Well the other issue I had is that in some cases in this procedure the type is set to a single value and other times it will be the result of my above query. By making it a variable I can then just use that and not have to worry about adding cases everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
declare @All nvarchar(1000)
SET @All=null

SELECT
    @All=ISNULL(@All+', ','')+CONVERT(varchar(10),d.value)
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS Value UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 333 UNION SELECT 4444) d

PRINT @All
```

OUTPUT:

```
1, 22, 333, 4444
```

this is what you can use:

```
SELECT
    @All=ISNULL(@All+', ','')+CONVERT(varchar(10),d.type)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT type 
              FROM dbo.table 
              WHERE building = @currentBuilding
         ) d
```